# How to trigger a function at regular intervals of time using hooks and when certain criteria is met I want to clear the time interval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component that performs a certain task at regular intervals of time after mounting. But I want to clear the interval once after a criterion is met. How can I achieve that?

My code

```
const [totalTime, setTotalTime] = React.useState(10000);

const foo = () => {
      console.log("Here");
  };

React.useEffect(() => {
    const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (totalTime > 0) setTotalTime(totalTime - 1000);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(secondInterval);
  });

React.useEffect(() => {
    let originalInterval;
    if (totalTime > 0)
      originalInterval = setInterval(() => {
        foo();
        console.log(totalTime);
      }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(originalInterval);
  }, []);
```

When I watch the console even after 10000ms It is still logging **Here** and also **totalTime** is always being 10000ms. I am not able to figure out what exactly is happening.

Comment: Please don't remove code from questions when answers are present that require the code for comparison or reference.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass the older state as an argument to the `setTotalTime` updater function. You also may need to pass (another) state variable as a dependency  to the `useEffect` hook so that the function is executed every time the state variable changes

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (totalTime > 0) setTotalTime(totalTime => totalTime - 1000);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(secondInterval);
  }, [...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your criteria, and what you call a criteria, but you could just use another state and then `useEffect` on that another state:

```
const [criteriaIsMet,setCriteriaIsMet] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => { if(criteriaIsMet) {clearInterval(...)} },[criteriaIsMet])
```

And then somewhere when you do your actual "criteria logic" you just go ahead and do `setCriteriaIsMet(true)`

And how would you know Id of interval in above `useEffect` - again you could just create a special state that will store that id, and you could set it in your original `useEffect`

As for why your current code is not clearing the interval is because when you use `useEffect` with empty array as second argument, and return function in first function argument - that will be execute on component unmounting

And these are just one of numerous options you have actually :)